# Boot-Repair utility asking me to open terminal and fire commands?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, bootrepair

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1. Installation is complete. Ubuntu has been installed.

Problem is, there is no GRUB. So of course I downloaded the famous [boot-repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and did the Recommended repair.

This boot-repair is installed on a separate USB stick and booted up.

Now the problem is that this utility, after doing whatever work it has to do, is asking me to open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" dpkg-configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get purge -y -force-yes grub*-common shim-signed linux-signed*
```

There's no terminal in the boot-repair utility. So there's no way for me to enter these commands.(There is an Xterm though. Should I use that?) Have you ever come across this? How do I resolve this issue?

[image: The window dialog asking me to run the commands]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/) *is* a terminal (or rather a terminal emulator). If you have one available, you can safely use that.